# The phrase 乞うご期待

Tags: set-phrases

What does the phrase 乞うご期待 mean in English? Can you show some example sentences?

Comment: What is wrong with this question?

Comment: I agree.  I see nothing wrong with this question.

Comment: I think the problem is that the person asking the question should be providing example sentences, not the people answering.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was reading this [chiebukuro](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q144975334), I think the gist of it is that movie theaters would give a preview of what they had coming to the screen, and a big **乞うご期待** would be written on the trailer. I guess this is like the **Coming Soon** in the U.S.

I can't translate it to English, but perhaps something along the lines of "for your anticipation."

To give the meaning, the same chiebukuro rewords it:

> [どうぞ]期待してください。 
>   Please look forward to this.

Comment: 乞う means "to request", so it would be "the expectation/anticipation of what you asked for".

Comment: I see, but can't you look at it from the other way around if we switch who's doing the asking, "request your anticipation"? I know, it sounds weird to me too.

Comment: It is a kanbun-influenced phrase (thus, not in standard Japanese word order) that means "We request 乞う your anticipation/looking-forward-to-ness ご期待". Sometimes you see it split into two sentences for ease of understanding: 乞う！ご期待！ It is a similar pattern to "求む (something)" which means "we want (something)!"